# Web user control in asp .Net page

Tags: asp.net

i have a dropdown control with Listitems in Web User control. Am using the web user control in an asp .net page. using find control am able to find the control dropdown but could not get the itemlist. Can any body help me to resolve the issue...?

Comment: can paste ur UC markup and codebehind code

Comment: Show your code how you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use find control.  Expose it as a property of your web user control instead.

If you still want to use FindControl, it is likely you can not find the item list because FindControl does not return a DropdownList.  You will need to cast the control returned as a `DropDownList` to access its `Items` property